# How can you integrate the Mule Amazon SNS connector behind corporate proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, mule, amazon-sns

I am trying to integrate the Mule Amazon SNS connector behind the corporate proxy and having much trouble to bypass the proxy. It always give me this error:

> [[snstest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01]
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request:
>   Connection to https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com refused

Exception stack is:

> 1. Unable to execute HTTP request: Connection to https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com refused
> 2. Failed to invoke createTopic. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
>      org.mule.modules.sns.processors.CreateTopicMessageProcessor:129

I believe the issue is the proxy trying to block the connection between the application and the amazon endpoint. When I try it at home with direct internet, it worked. Also, I have also tried `http:connector` and `http:proxy` to configure the proxy and it has not worked at all.

Comment: can you hit https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com from a browser or via curl? it sounds like you need to configure a proxy for the traffic to reach the amazon endpoint

Comment: When I try to hit sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com via Chrome, it gives me this: <UnknownOperationException/>

Comment: that's okay. The unknown operation exception is expected. Is chrome using an http proxy?

Comment: http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check http://www.checkingtools.com/proxy_check to check if you are using a proxy.

Comment: Yes, my Chrome was configured with http proxy. I think this is the sns connector's problem. This connector might be written by some individual programmer and has not been sufficiently verified by MuleSoft, and they forgot to add the proxy configuration within the connector

Answer (score 0):

Check the secret key and access key. Issue is not with proxy its problem in credentials.